# Google Oauth per minute rate limits

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-platform, jwt, google-oauth, google-authentication

I have a project in production that uses Google Oauth for authentication purposes. It does not access any sensitive scopes, just the userId, email and profile info. But whenever I have used google authentication on my application, the graph tracking token grant rate limits keeps showing "No data is available for the selected time frame". I am not able to keep track of token grant limit of my application and it says 100 grants per minute which might become a potential bottleneck for my application. Does accessing only non-sensitive scopes not count in token grant rate-limits?

[image: Graph tracking token grant rate limits keeps showing "No data is available for the selected time frame"]

Answer (score 0):

First off this graph is not real-time.  Second its not known to be very accurate.  When it does start showing data you should consider requesting an extension when you hit about 80% of your current quota.

[OAuth Application Rate Limits](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9028764?hl=en)